# Jersey ValidationException message not always the same

Tags: api, validation, jersey

In an API I'm working on, I've the following definition:

```
@PUT
@Path("/{messageTypeId}")
@Consumes({ "application/json" })
@Produces({ "application/json" })
@ApiOperation(value = "Amend the Message Type.", notes = "Amend the Message Type.", tags={  })
@ApiResponses(value = { 
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successful response.", response = Void.class),
    @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request.", response = Problem.class),
    @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found.", response = Problem.class),
    @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal Server Error.", response = Problem.class),
    @ApiResponse(code = 503, message = "Service Unavailable.", response = Problem.class) })
void amendMessageType_(@PathParam("messageTypeId") @Size(max=255) @ApiParam("Message Type Unique Identifier") String messageTypeId,@Valid MessageTypeAmendBody messageTypeBody) throws Exception;
```

There is an ExceptionMapper when a ValidationException occurs, to catch and format in JSON the error. It appears that the mapper receives sometimes a message like that:

```
arg0 is not correct, must be between 0 and 255
```

and sometimes

```
messageTypeId is not correct, must be between 0 and 255
```

It's the case when I run the unit test from IntelliJ (I get the first one) and from Maven (the second one) or when I run the application (one or the other)... Do you have ideas ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue, I had to add a compilation flag:

```
<compilerArgs>
    <arg>-parameters</arg>
</compilerArgs>
```

to the Maven compiler plugin.